How to provide nth template parameter without specifying every template parameter before?
Suppose you have a template type like this:
type T<A = DefaultA, B = DefaultB, C = DefaultC> = A & B & C; // just for demo purposes 

Now when I want to specify the last template parameter C I need to count through all the defaults before and only then specify it.
const t: T<DefaultA, DefaultB, MyC> | undefined;

Is there any less verbose way of writing it?

No, you'd have to rewrite your type in some way. See the linked q/a for more information.

@jcalz What do you think, is it even a good idea to give a programmer an ability to use template parameters as a named key-value pairs e.g const t: T<C = MyC>?

It seems like a reasonable idea, but TS doesn't do named type parameters. You could use an object type like type T<X extends {A?: any, B?: any, C?: any}={}> = Fallback<X, "A", DefaultA> & Fallback<X, "B", DefaultB> & Fallback<X, "C", DefaultC> where maybe type Fallback<T, K, D> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : D and then you'd have const t: T<{C: MyC}>.  See playground link

@jcalz It seems like an interesting idea, however in most cases I have problems with already written types in library code, so the only solution is probably to implement it on a language level or as a babel macro.

I'm confused, if the types are already written, then what's the problem? The types don't work? Given that named type parameters and skippable defaults aren't part of the language, I'm not sure what we're talking about.

@jcalz I'm sorry if I was unclear, for example I have an Express library with exported type Request this type has 5 generic parameters and parameter Locals is the last one, I have no way of rewriting the generic type of a Request itself, therefore I need to create my own Request type with solution similar to yours and use it inside of my codebase only, the problem with this approach is that for each library I need to write quite fat redefinitions for each type to be able to use them like that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
